# Files of text/plain type is transferred much faster than other mime types

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, mime-types

I have a HTTP file transfer java application.

I have observed that text files (plain/text mime type) of higher size are transferred much faster than other binary files of lower size.

In my client I am using Java script XMLHttpRequest to download the file.

I first keep the file in a blob (browser memory) using response type "blob" and then save it to the file system by using a href.

is there any specific reason of why this is happening. Is it because of the blob saving ?

Comment: Does changing **only** the response’s `Content-Type`, while keeping everything else (same file, same client code), make it faster?

Comment: Also note that `plain/text` is not a [registered media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). You probably want `text/plain`.

Comment: Compression, maybe?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov i meant text/plain only...client code is same only.

Comment: @JulianReschke it was indeed compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of compression (see transfer-encoding/content-encoding "gzip").